# Run-time error 9: Index out of range when accessing a simple array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've run into a problem, I cannot seem to figure out, using basic array functionalities. I'm using the following (standard) code:

```
Sub CC()

Dim arrB As Variant
arrB = Sheet2.Range("B3:B100").Value2

Debug.Print LBound(arrB) & " " & UBound(arrB)
Debug.Print arrB(LBound(arrB))

End Sub
```

The first `Debug.Print` statement returns "1 98" as expected. But when I try to access any values inside the array `arrB` with my second `Debug.Print` I'm getting a run-time error 9 (Index out of range). Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try `Debug.Print arrB(LBound(arrB),1)`

Comment: That was quick, thank you! Somehow I didn't think of the array's second dimension since I'm only putting one column of values into it. Feel free to post it as an answer, so the question can be closed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Debug.Print arrB(LBound(arrB),1)
```

For future tasks with arrays - that was quick because I had many many struggles before, the easiest way to deal with arrays is to **Add Watch** on them.

By that You would see how it looks and how many dimensions it has :)

I'm glad that I could help :)

Comment: Described problem on https://simpleexcelvba.com/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range-array/